# how to convert bit array into hex contanning 8bits in java

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation, hexdump

I have binary array i converted into hex using

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) 
    {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

But it gives me hex code for its respective bit.

I want hex containing 8bits. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this-

```
BigInteger bInt = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
String hexString = String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "X", bInt);
```

For lower case hex digits, you can use-

```
String hexString = String.format("%0" + (bytes.length << 1) + "x", bInt);
```